# Copy files from LXC to host machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, container, lxc

I'm new to containers. I have a LXC container running on a remote linux machine. All I found online is how to copy files from host to LXC container. But how can I copy files from a running LXC container to the host, and eventually to my own machine?

Maybe it seems trivial that I couldn't find anything. I'm new and am a bit confused.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/731587/86801.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it the other way around. So SCP a local folder on the LXC container to the host machine:

```
scp -r /root/[container folder] root@10.0.3.1:/root/[host folder to put files in]
```

Comment: 10.0.3.1 is the interface IP shown on the host.

Answer (score 3):

Install a **SSH server** on your LXC container. Allow connections from remote hosts to port TCP 22. From your own machine connect to your LXC container using SCP with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) (for Windows). In case you are using Linux on your own machine just use the [scp](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ssh-and-scp-with-public-key-authentication/) command from console.

Comment: You are unnecesarily exposing SSH service in your container. See my comment in the OP question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `lxc file pull`

```
lxc file pull [<remote>:]<instance>/<path> [[<remote>:]<instance>/<path>...] <target path> [flags]
```

Comment: It is important to note that this functionality is not actually part of LXC but of LXD.